# convert the image to rgb so that i can visualize the image

Tags: python-3.x, image-resizing, simpleitk

I am trying to segment an image but not able to apply to rescale intensity to the image

I have tried to reshape the image and apply the rescaleintensity but was not able to get it

```
 def load_sitk_image(path,vol_size=np.array([128,128,64]),dst_res=[1,1,1],method = sitk.sitkLinear ) :

img = sitk.ReadImage(path)

ret = np.zeros([vol_size[0], vol_size[1], vol_size[2]], dtype=np.float32)

#we rotate the image according to its transformation using the direction and according to the final spacing we want

factor = np.asarray(img.GetSpacing()) / [dst_res[0], dst_res[1],dst_res[2]]

factorSize = np.asarray(img.GetSize() * factor, dtype=float)

newSize = np.max([factorSize, vol_size], axis=0)

newSize = newSize.astype(dtype='int')

T=sitk.AffineTransform(3)

T.SetMatrix(img.GetDirection())

resampler = sitk.ResampleImageFilter()

resampler.SetReferenceImage(img)

resampler.SetOutputSpacing([dst_res[0], dst_res[1], dst_res[2]])

resampler.SetSize(newSize.tolist())

resampler.SetInterpolator(method)

imgResampled = resampler.Execute(img)

imgCentroid = np.asarray(newSize, dtype=float) / 2.0

imgStartPx = (imgCentroid - vol_size / 2.0).astype(dtype='int')

regionExtractor = sitk.RegionOfInterestImageFilter()

size_2_set = vol_size.astype(dtype='int')

regionExtractor.SetSize(size_2_set.tolist())

regionExtractor.SetIndex(imgStartPx.tolist())

imgResampledCropped = regionExtractor.Execute(imgResampled)

ret = np.transpose(sitk.GetArrayFromImage(imgResampledCropped).astype(dtype=float),[0,1,2])

ret = (ret - ret.min())/(ret.max()-ret.min())

#ret = (ret - ret.mean())/ret.std()

return ret

img_T1 = load_sitk_image(path = r"C:\Users\chinnu\Desktop\post processing project\training part 1\case01.mhd")

img_T2 = load_sitk_image(path =r"C:\Users\chinnu\Desktop\post processing project\training\Case01_segmentation.mhd")


img_T1_255 = sitk.Cast(sitk.RescaleIntensity(img_T1), sitk.sitkUInt8)
```

### > **error:**

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      3 
      4 
----> 5 img_T1_255 = sitk.Cast(sitk.RescaleIntensity(img_T1), sitk.sitkUInt8)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\SimpleITK\SimpleITK.py in RescaleIntensity(image1, outputMinimum, outputMaximum)
  59087 
  59088     """

> 59089     return _SimpleITK.RescaleIntensity(image1, outputMinimum, outputMaximum)
>     59090 class RichardsonLucyDeconvolutionImageFilter(ImageFilter_2):
>     59091     """

TypeError: in method 'RescaleIntensity', argument 1 of type 'itk::simple::Image const &'

i expect that result like i can apply the rescale intensity

Comment: can you format this question so all code is a bit clearer and provide the input data used?

Comment: i have edited the code please look into it

Comment: check the type of 'img_T1' - I think you are returning a numpy array in your load_sitk_image function. You need to use GetImageFromArray to return an SimpleITK.Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the type of 'img_T1' - I think you are returning a numpy array in your load_sitk_image function. You need to use GetImageFromArray to return an SimpleITK.Image